# I cannot use `async def set` for my command | discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Basically I have made a Command Group and I want to have set in that group. Basically whenever someone types `>prefix` a message will show up saying it's commands and then whenever I use `>prefix set` it will basically change it's prefix. The problem is that I can not use `set` for the `async def`. I can use anything else apart from that. Why is that and how can I fix it?

**My Code:**

````
    @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True, manage_guild = True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def prefix(self, ctx):
        
        try:
            x = ""
            prefix = await self.client.get_prefix(ctx)

            PrefixEmbed = discord.Embed(title = x, description = f"My Prefix for ***__{ctx.guild}__***, is `{prefix}`. For more Information, type `{prefix}Help`.\n\nAvailable Commands:```{prefix}prefix set\n{prefix}prefix reset```")
            PrefixEmbed.set_author(name = "ChizLanks Prefix System", icon_url = self.client.user.avatar_url)
            PrefixEmbed.set_footer(text = f"Guild's ID: {ctx.guild.id}", icon_url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
            PrefixEmbed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            await ctx.reply(embed = PrefixEmbed)
        
        except discord.Forbidden:
            x = ""
            prefix = await self.client.get_prefix(ctx)

            PrefixEmbed = discord.Embed(title = x, description = f"My Prefix for ***__{ctx.guild}__***, is `{prefix}`. For more Information, type `{prefix}Help`.\n\nAvailable Commands:```{prefix}prefix set\n{prefix}prefix reset```")
            PrefixEmbed.set_author(name = "ChizLanks Prefix System", icon_url = self.client.user.avatar_url)
            PrefixEmbed.set_footer(text = f"Guild's ID: {ctx.guild.id}", icon_url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
            PrefixEmbed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            await ctx.author.send(embed = PrefixEmbed)

    @prefix.error
    async def k_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            try:
                x = ""
                prefix = await self.client.get_prefix(ctx)
                PrefixEmbed = discord.Embed(title = x, description = f"My Prefix for ***__{ctx.guild}__***, is `{prefix}`. For more Information, type `{prefix}Help`.")
                PrefixEmbed.set_author(name = "ChizLanks Prefix System", icon_url = self.client.user.avatar_url)
                PrefixEmbed.set_footer(text = f"Guild's ID: {ctx.guild.id}", icon_url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
                PrefixEmbed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                await ctx.reply(embed = PrefixEmbed)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                x = ""
                prefix = await self.client.get_prefix(ctx)
                PrefixEmbed = discord.Embed(title = x, description = f"My Prefix for ***__{ctx.guild}__***, is `{prefix}`. For more Information, type `{prefix}Help`.")
                PrefixEmbed.set_author(name = "ChizLanks Prefix System", icon_url = self.client.user.avatar_url)
                PrefixEmbed.set_footer(text = f"Guild's ID: {ctx.guild.id}", icon_url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
                PrefixEmbed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                await ctx.author.send(embed = PrefixEmbed)
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            await ctx.reply('You are being Rate Limited. Please, try again in `{:.2f}` Second(s).'.format(error.retry_after), delete_after = 5)

    @prefix.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True, manage_guild = True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def set(self, ctx, prefix):

        db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM prefixes WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO prefixes(guild_id, prefix) VALUES(?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id, prefix)
            await ctx.reply(f"Server Prefix has been set and saved as `{prefix}`")
        elif result is not None:
            sql = ("UPDATE prefixes SET prefix = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
            val = (prefix, ctx.guild.id)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"Server Prefix has been updated and saved as `{prefix}`.")
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the function however you want, then pass the `name` kwarg to the decorator

```py
@prefix.command(name="set")
async def _set(self, ctx):
    ...
```

I cannot reproduce the issue here, so I can't tell you why you can't set the name to `set`